# variable scope in pragma omp simd reduction

Tags: c++, openmp, vectorization, simd

using openmp simd with reduction seems to be restricting the variable scope of a nested loop.

```
  int N = 5;
  double* list0 = new double[N] ();
  double* list1 = new double[N] ();
  double* list2 = new double[N] ();


  for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    #pragma omp simd reduction(+:list0[i],list1[i],list2[i])
    for (int j=0; j<N; j++){

      list0[i] += i*j;
      list1[i] += i*j;
      list2[i] += i*j;
    }
  }
  printf("  %f\n",list0[4]);
```

When the pragma is commented out, this prints the correct answer, 40. But with the pragma every value in each of the lists remains at 0. how can I get it to actually change the values?

Comment: That's a limitation (bug?) of GCC. Compiling with Clang produces the expected result.

Comment: do you happen to know if it works with intel's icpc?

Comment: (it does, i just checked)